# Android - Is it possible to access instrumened test and unit test classes in androidTest and test folders programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way to access the test classes in AndroidTest and test folders from my code? I can access tests placed in the same folder than my activity but not from these test folders.

Here is a picture to explain what I mean:

[image]

I am using Android Studio and Kotlin.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Not sure why you would want that

Comment: @TimCastelijns I want to do that to run test after an admin clicked a button. I use JunitCore to do that.

Comment: You can set up a CI that supports testing and executes then at the click of a button, or a single GUI/.sh file that executes the testing. From android though, without CI, you can't. It's not bundled into the app, and some testing is still done locally on the JVM and not an Android device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to access the test classes in androidTest and test folders from code?

If by "from code" you mean "from classes in the `main/` source set", then no, that is not possible.

> I want to do that to run test after an admin clicked a button.

Android tests (`androidTest` and `test`) are run by the Android SDK tools. Unit tests (`test`) are run on a development machine, not the device. Instrumented tests (`androidTest`) require special permissions to run and cannot be executed directly by an ordinary Android app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I am settled :)